# UITabBarItem background set by UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage misaligned on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

The code:

```
let size = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(TabBarItem.allValues.count),
                  height: tabBar.frame.height)
let image = UIImage.image(color: Color.action, size: size)
UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = image
```

On usual devices looks like this:

[image]

On iPhone X like this:

[image]

What can be the reason why iPhone X tab bar item background is misaligned?

---

**UPDATE 1**:

After changing code to be like below it looks better but it is still workaround as image not fully occupies tab bar item space:

```
  var image: UIImage
  if DeviceInfo.is5p8Inch {
     image = UIImage.image(color: Color.action, size: CGSize(width: 4, height: 4))
     image = image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2), resizingMode: .tile)
  } else {
     let size = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(TabBarItem.allValues.count),
                       height: tabBar.frame.height)
     image = UIImage.image(color: Color.action, size: size)
  }
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Code above called from `viewDidLoad` (also tries from `viewWillAppear`). Subclass of `UITabBarController` written 100% from code (no Storyboards/Xibs used).

---

**UPDATE 3**:

We also have a custom button added as subview to UITabBar which positioned correctly. Only `selectionIndicatorImage` is misaligned...

[image]

---

**UPDATE 4**:

Running original code above in `viewDidAppear` instead of in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` produces following result:

[image]

Comment: use programmatically TabbarController which will not affect this issues

Comment: We are not using Storyboards and xibs. TabbarController written 100% from code .)

Comment: @Vlad try setting frame as `CGSize(width:(appdelegate.window?.frame.size.width)!/5,height: 49)`

Comment: Seems no difference: `UIApplication.shared.delegate!.window!!.frame.size.width` is 375, `tabBar.frame.width` is 375, `tabBar.frame.height` is 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call it after delay because it didn't get correct height of tabBar in your case and set it in self.tabBar, bellow code works for me i did it in `viewDidload`

```
Async.main {
        let size = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(TabBarItem.allValues.count),
                          height: tabBar.frame.height)
        let image = UIImage.image(color: Color.action, size: size)
        UITabBar.appearance().selectionIndicatorImage = image
        self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = image // this will change color and height of current tabBar
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Async call from `viewDidLoad` fixes issue.) There is `blinking` artefact at the end of TabTar appearance, but it is way better than before.

Answer (score 0):

try, this worked for me. not sure if it will work for all.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        tabbar.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
```

Comment: With original code at the top of question call to `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` produces result with the same issue on iPhone X :0

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

Make extension of image which generate color image.

```
extension UIImage {

    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

And set that image to tabbarcontroller and set 48 height of tabbar

```
var tabFrame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame
    //self.TabBar is IBOutlet of your TabBar
    tabFrame.size.height = 48
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.window!.frame.size.height - 48

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = tabFrame
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.autoresizesSubviews = false
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self
    tabNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self.tabBarController)
    tabNavigation.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat((tabBarController.tabBar.items!.count))
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBarController.tabBar.frame.width) / numberOfItems,
                                height: (tabBarController.tabBar.frame.height))
    tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor(red: 90/255.0, green: 43/255.0, blue:123/255.0, alpha: 1.0), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)
    tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width = self.window!.frame.width + 4
    tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
```

Comment: We have the method `UIImage.image(color: Color.action, size: size)` listed in question identical to proposed `UIImage` extension.) Using `.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero)` produces result with the same issue on iPhone X :0

Comment: @Vlad please check updated code. and need to set height to 48 of tabbar.

Comment: With frame manipulation I got shifted `selectionIndicatorImage` and icons down.)